# Ansible: set UseDNS to "no" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Tags: ansible

I want to update the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set `UseDNS no`.

I would like to update only this value, and not to use a template for the whole file.

Is there a generic way to set key-value based configs (with unix-config-style) with ansible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use the `lineinfile` module for it, like this:

```
- name: Update the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/ssh/sshd_config
    regexp: "^UseDNS"
    line: "UseDNS no"
    insertafter: EOF
    state: present
  register: ssh_config

- name: Restart ssh
  service:
    name: ssh
    state: restarted
  when: ssh_config.changed
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatically restart sshd after the file was changed?